# Mutual Auth in Jboss vs WebSphere

Tags: jboss, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm working on Jboss 5 and WAS 7.
I was able to run my application via Mutual Authentication on Jboss following this doc,
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SSLSetup/

Following the above doc I created server.keystore and server.truststore files that I injected into the Jboss server and everything works fine.

Now, I want to run the same application via Mutual Auth on WAS.
On WAS, the trust store and keystore are specified by navigating to

> Security > SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > New > Key
>   stores and certificates

But there I don't see any type related to .keystore and .truststore.(snap below)
[image]

My question - **what is the equivalent of .keystore and .truststore that can be used in WAS** OR **what's the way to set up a Browser based Mutual Authentication on a WAS server**.
I'm using WAS 7.0.0.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eglce/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.eglce.developing.doc/topics/pegl_richui_security_sslexample.html) helped me setup SSL on WAS. I just had to add a couple of steps to enable it for Browser based Mutual Authentication.

Since, I had to do a POC hence I'm using Self Signed Certificates.

In a ideal scenario Certificates will be signed by a Certificate Authority and the Certificate of Certificate Authority will be imported to the Trust Store of a WAS Server.

Here are the steps,

1. Change the password for Default KeyStore and Default TrustStore in WAS
2. Create a Client Certificate in WAS
3. Create a Server Certificate in WAS
4. Export the Client Certificate in PKCS format, e.g. client.p12
5. Export the Server Certificate in PKCS format, e.g. server.p12
6. Import the Client Certificate to Default TrustStore
7. Import the Server Certificate to Default TrustStore
8. Enable SSL on WAS.

   i. Make sure the to select server certificate for both Default server certificate alias and the Default client certificate alias.

   ii. In the Quality of protection (QoP) settings, choose Client Authentication as Required.
9. Create a Web Container Transport Chain with a new SSL port, e.g. 9444.
10. Add the newly created SSL port to the virtual Host.
11. Restart the Server.
12. Import the Client Certificate created in Step 4 client.p12 to the Browser.

Comment: Good detail. A few thoughts:  
2 & 4. Often the client certificate will be created/issued by a third party and you'll just be importing the public portion of it in WAS.  
7. You would be importing the exported server certificate (public key) into the client's trust store (FF or IE), not into WAS' Default TrustStore.

Comment: "you'll just be importing the public portion of it in WAS" - Yes you are correct. But what I have seen with Enterprises is that, they don't import individual certificates. They only import the public portion of a Certificate Authority to WAS which has signed the individual certificates. Also in an Enterprise, they generally use CAC Cards and not browser. I was constrained with limited resources to do a POC of my application, hence used the browser based way.

Answer (score 1):

Keystores and truststores are the same format in WebSphere. You choose the file format, but any of those formats can be used for either store.

You then point a configuration at specific files.

> Security > SSL certificate and key management > Manage endpoint security configurations

Alternatively, what has been simpler for us is to use the existing default stores WebSphere already has and add our certificates to those.

> Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > CellDefaultKeyStore

Or `CellDefaultTrustStore` or `NodeDefaultKeyStore`, etc.

Comment: I tried but no format other than PKCS12 came to rescue. In my browser based Mutual Authentication, none of the formats other than the .p12 is acceptable to FF or IE. So, I had to stick to PKCS12 format. Anyways I've been able to successfully setup a Mutual Auth between a client browser and a WAS server. Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: You don't have to use the same file format on the server as you use on the client. You just have to export the public portion into a format that the other side can import.